# ipfs files ls not showing all the files uploaded to it

Tags: ipfs

When I am using ipfs files ls, it is not showing all the files which are being added.
But when I am searching the files in ipfs explorer through the hash I am getting the file.

Answer (score 2):

Files uploaded directly through the UI will be displayed. Files uploaded from console or using ifps-http-client (npm module) cannot be seen in the UI files section.

They can be fetched using the following two terminal commands

1. ipfs ls <your_root_resource_hash>
2. ipfs refs -r <your_root_resource_hash>

In the latest version of ipfs, the uploaded files are visible in the files section of ipfs UI